# modeling a stadium and import it to PES 2017

Tags: modeling

one day my client told me to model a stadium for the game PES 2017.I used some references to do my best but the client cannot answer my questions like:1)how to put grass on soccer field(i dont know actually if I use particle system it works correctly in the game or not)another question is applying transform and scale of the model for the game.should I place the model in 0,0,0 and the scale in 1,1,1?last one is creating CPK format to be accepted in the game.I don't know how to create such these with models and textures?I hope there is someone to give me a hand or advice.
thanks(btw I work with blender).

Comment: Hello :). Please keep it one *specific* question per post. You're welcome to post as many *separate* questions as you need.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like a question for BSE since it's really more about PES. Maybe you should ask a modding community.